# UITableViewCell subclass with Auto Layout constraints incorrectly sized

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios8

I'm attempting to programmatically create a custom `UITableViewCell`, no XIB, that consists of a single `UILabel` that uses Auto Layout to specify the cell's height. I've given this label leading, trailing, top, and bottom constraints to the cell's `contentView` yet these constraints aren't affecting the table view cell's height. The labels are all stacked on top of each other without padding and the table view separator lines don't line up with the labels either. What is the problem here?

[image]

Custom cell:

```
@interface TransactionTableViewCell ()

@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL didUpdateConstraints;

@end


@implementation TransactionTableViewCell

- (instancetype)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {

    if (self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier]) {
        self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

        self.transactionPriceLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
        self.transactionPriceLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
        self.transactionPriceLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
        [self.contentView addSubview:self.transactionPriceLabel];
    }

    [self setNeedsUpdateConstraints]; //had to add this otherwise updateConstraints isn't called for some reason

    return self;

}

- (void)updateConstraints {
    if (!self.didUpdateConstraints) {
        self.didUpdateConstraints = YES;

        [self.contentView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.transactionPriceLabel
                                                                     attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing
                                                                     relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                        toItem:self.contentView
                                                                     attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing
                                                                    multiplier:1
                                                                      constant:-15]];
        [self.contentView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.transactionPriceLabel
                                                                     attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                                     relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                        toItem:self.contentView
                                                                     attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                                    multiplier:1
                                                                      constant:15]];
        [self.contentView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.transactionPriceLabel
                                                                     attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                                                     relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                        toItem:self.contentView
                                                                     attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                                                    multiplier:1
                                                                      constant:15]];
        [self.contentView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.transactionPriceLabel
                                                                     attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading
                                                                     relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                        toItem:self.contentView
                                                                     attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading
                                                                    multiplier:1
                                                                      constant:15]];
    }

    [super updateConstraints];
}
```

View Controller:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    UITableView *tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
    tableView.dataSource = self;
    tableView.delegate = self;
    tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
    tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44.0;
    [self.view addSubview:tableView];

    tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    [self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:tableView
                                                     attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading
                                                     relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                        toItem:self.view
                                                     attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading
                                                    multiplier:1
                                                      constant:0]];
    [self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:tableView
                                                     attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                     relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                        toItem:self.view
                                                     attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                    multiplier:1
                                                      constant:0]];
    [self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:tableView
                                                     attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                                     relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                        toItem:self.view
                                                     attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                                    multiplier:1
                                                      constant:0]];
    [self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:tableView
                                                     attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailingMargin
                                                     relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                        toItem:self.view
                                                     attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailingMargin
                                                    multiplier:1
                                                      constant:0]];

    [tableView registerClass:[TransactionTableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 10;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    TransactionTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.transactionPriceLabel.text = @"label text";
    cell.transactionPriceLabel.textColor = [UIColor redColor];

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The constant for the bottom of the label to the bottom of the contentView constraint should be -15, not 15.

Comment: Good eye! Wow it was that simple.